# Conversion to datetime is yielding error "ValueError: day is out of range for month" How to find

Tags: datetime, pandas

I have a huge dataframe that looks something like this:

```
                    Insider Trading                   Relationship    Date  \
SEC Form 4                                                                   
Nov 16 04:06 PM      Silverman Gene                       Director  Nov 14   
Oct 27 07:00 AM     RAKOLTA JOHN JR                       Director  Oct 26   
Nov 16 04:09 PM  LEIGHTON F THOMSON        Chief Executive Officer  Nov 15   
Nov 02 04:20 PM      Blumofe Robert                   EVP Platform  Nov 01   
Oct 28 04:03 PM    MCCONNELL RICK M  President Prods & Development  Oct 28
```

I'm trying to change the index dtype into a  datetime dtype via this code

```
pd.to_datetime(df2.index, format = '%b %d %I:%M %p')
```

but it's yielding the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#126>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.to_datetime(df2.index, format = '%b %d %I:%M %p')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py", line 420, in to_datetime
    return _convert_listlike(arg, box, format, name=arg.name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py", line 407, in _convert_listlike
raise e
```

Is there a way I can find the index of where the error is occurring?
It seems I can set `errors` to `coerce` which would just return a `Nan` as the date, but I would like to avoid that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are right, just finish the logic. Set to coerce and filter the index against all values being isnull() to find all the incorrect indices.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the incorrect indices were in  Feb, which makes me assume they were for the 29th. I couldn't find an option to include leap years. Is there no such option? 

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: Lookup the original strings of dates in the column before conversion. What do they look like?

Comment: I checked the first few original dates and they indeed seem to be Feb 29. I used this code to replace them:

`df.index = df.index.fillna('1900-02-28')`   It seems to be doing the trick. I'm surprised  29 days in Feb isn't taken into account when trying to convert into datetime.